# bitcoind jsonrpc bumpfee not returning hash of newly created transaction

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, bumpfee

I'm trying to implement replace by fee functionality with bictoind (v18) and bumpfee rpc call described [here](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#bumpfee)

It works by mean that new transaction is created with higher fee, but result should be:

```
{
  "txid":    "value",   (string)  The id of the new transaction
  "origfee":  n,         (numeric) Fee of the replaced transaction
  "fee":      n,         (numeric) Fee of the new transaction
  "errors":  [ str... ] (json array of strings) Errors encountered during processing (may be empty)
}
```

but I'm getting basically all null response

```
{
  "id": "BumpFeeRequest 1561247020661",
  "error": null,
  "txid": null,
  "origfee": null,
  "fee": null,
  "errors": null
}
```

Which makes it hard to identify the new transaction in down-steam system.

How can I get the txid, except querying for last tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not bug of bitcoind, but java lib I was using. Bitcoind works fine

Answer (score 0):

the issue is now tracked on https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/16275...